# AS3: One class with parameter, or two similar classes

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface

In case of creating two similar custom AS3 visual components, ex. Button, with different look, but same function, which methodology is better, more efficient from the aspect of code-execution, speed, performance?

1. Creating two, almost identical classes, where the only difference is
   in the visual components, so I have to write the button-controlling functions two times?
2. Creating one class, with a parameter input
   that defines, which kind of button I would like to have

**1:**

```
package {
            public class bigButton {
                public function bigButton() {
                    //make a bigButton
                }
            }
}
```

and

```
 package {
                public class smallButton {


                    public function smallButton() {
                        //make a smallButton
                    }
                }
 }
```

or

**2:**

```
package {
        public class OneKindOfButton {
            public function OneKindOfButton(thisIsBigButton:Boolean) {
                if (thisIsBigButton == true) {
                     //make it big
                } else {
                     //make it small
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of an academic argument about the two structures (not this particular example), I'd have to argue that the first option is "better."  Although opinion based posts are generally regarded as worthless by most of the SO community, I have a couple of points to bring up and would like to hear counter arguments.

For the second option of doing it, first off it makes me think that potentially there should be a base class that contains all the original functionality then a sub-class that tweaks some part of the functionality.  Secondly it requires a condition in the constructor (and probably elsewhere littered throughout that class) to deal with the two scenarios the one class is handling.  I think part of the issue here is that in AS3 there is a tendency to mash up all of the functionality and the view logic into one class, just because it's possible doesn't make it a good idea.

All said, I would probably go the route of having a base class that contains the functionality for the buttons, then make some sub-classes that do things different visually.

Also in terms of run-time efficiency I believe the first scenario will work out better again due to the extra conditions that will have to be checked at run-time with the second scenario.  In any case, when performance and optimization is the issue it's always best to just run a test (build a little test app that makes 10,000 of each, run it a couple of times and get an average).

Comment: Agree that there should be one base class, but since the differences are visual, there's no reason for the hand-written Actionscript side to address the differences between the types of buttons at all. Let Flash generate the subclasses in the background for the library instances.

Comment: Ah I follow Amy.  I was thinking only from my perspective (Flash Builder developer) hadn't considered the Flash IDE and the library.

Answer (score 2):

I would just create one kind of button class since you can draw or add other display objects into it. You don't even need a boolean to control that. For example :

```
public class OneKindOfButton extends Sprite{


    public function OneKindOfButton(width:Number,height:Number) {
        create(width,height);
    }


    private function create(width:Number,height:Number):void
    {
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,1.0);
        graphics.drawRect(0,0,width,height);
        graphics.endFill();
    }

}
```

Now you can use this class to create any size of button.

```
var myButton:OneKindOfButton = new OneKindOfButton(200,20);
myButton.x = 100;
myButton.y = 300;
addChild(myButton);
```

If you want to use images instead of drawing into the button you can do that too by just adding bitmaps into the button sprite.

Answer (score 1):

I think all these answers kind of miss the point of Flash.

Firstly, I don't think that View classes should *ever* have constructor arguments in Flash, because right off the bat you're making it impossible to ever use them on the timeline/stage. The Flash player can't (and shouldn't) provide these constructor arguments. The stage and timeline are Flash's biggest strength, so if you're not using them, you're wasting at least 25% of your time (the time where you're setting x, y, width, height, drawing graphics programmatically and all that unnecessary crap). Why lock yourself into a design that actively prevents you from using all the tools at your disposal?

The way I do it is I have *one* Class that defines the *behavior* of the button. Then the buttons are differentiated by having a library symbol for the big button, one for the small button, one for the button shaped like a pig, one for the button that looks like a spaceship, whatever. Any of these symbols will have that single Button Class as the Base Class (or more likely, just be defined as a Button in the library, so they subcass SimpleButton). Then I just place an instance of the library symbol on the stage and the variable in whatever parent Class is typed to my Button Class or SimpleButton.

The advantage of doing this is that the parent Classes don't need to know the specific implementation type, just the more general type. This means that the library symbols can have "export for Actionscript in frame N" unchecked, and they can just be compiled in where they are used. This means that initial load time can be reduced to the point that you may not ever need a preloader, depending on what else you have going on.

For more on this approach, see [Combining the Timeline with OOP in AS3](http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html).

Comment: Not everyone uses the Flash authoring tools, it is perfectly possible to create games/app with FlashDevelop and as3, and I don't see any problems with using constructor arguments. It doesn't prevent you from using the stage.

Comment: It is possible to _start_ in FlashDevelop, Flash Builder, or what have you, but then you may want to move to something a bit more full-featured. Just because _you_ don't see any problems with it does not mean they don't exist. How exactly do you get constructor arguments _into_ an instance that you've placed on stage?

Comment: I have developed full apps and games in Flash Develop, what I am saying is you don't have to use Flash Professional if your work flow is just using assets (can be swfs or pngs) and developing purely in Flash Develop/Flash Builder. Obviously the work flow in Flash Profiessional might be different, I don't use it so I can't answer `How exactly do you get constructor arguments into an instance that you've placed on stage?` But that is not a problem if you are doing your app/game purely in Flash Develop/Flash Builder.

Comment: ..until you decide that's not what you want anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference between you two buttons is their look, but all the logic is shared, then you should definitely use only one common class.

If you're dealing with spark button, then you can simply specify a different skin for each of your instances ([about spark skins](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSC8DB0C28-F7A6-48ff-9899-7957415A0A49.html)).

```
package
{
    import spark.component.Button;

    public class MyCustomButton extends Button
    {
        static public const SMALL:String = "smallButton";
        static public const BIG:String   = "bigButton";

        static private const DEFAULT_SIZE:String = SMALL;

        public function MyCustomButton(type:String = DEFAULT_SIZE)
        {
            super();

            if (type == SMALL)
            {
                setStyle("skinClass", SmallButtonSkin);
            }
            else
            {
                setStyle("skinClass", BigButtonSkin);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You then have to create to different skin classes where you'll define the visual logic of your buttons.