# Passing Model to View constructor for Stage Instances

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, model-view-controller, flash-cs5

I'm looking for an elegant solution to setting the Model argument for a View that is a stage instance.

My View constructor looks like this:

```
public function View($model:Model, $controller:IController=null){ ... }
```

My Subclass constructor:

```
public function ViewSubClass($model:Model, $controller:IController=null){ ... }
```

The idea is that the subclass will be a UI element that I'd rather just have on stage and not have to position it manually. I've thrown around the possibility of having placeholder elements that get removed and using their positions to attach the real UI elements but it seems a little hackish to me.

I suppose I could always set the default value of the $model argument in View to null, but not all views will be stage instances so I don't exactly want to do that either.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is :) Why won't your constructor work for a View which inherits Stage? And BTW I don't get why you would want to inherit Stage, but that's another problem.

Comment: I think he means the item will be placed on stage manually at design time rather than instantiated at runtime and then added to the stage using addChild.

Comment: @Kodiak Model is an object that gets created via the document class. This Model is then required by the View classes/subclasses constructor for instantiation. Unfortunately for stage instances, I can't exactly pass the model to it.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Oh OK, I hadn't understood you were designing with Flash.

Comment: @Kodiak My mistake - I should have added Flash to the tags. I forget that the Flash IDE isn't implied sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the ViewSubClass constructor to:

```
public function ViewSubClass ($model:Model=null, $controller:IController=null){ ... }
```

Not sure why I was thinking that the constructor had to match the superclass' constructor perfectly. I'm still open to more elegant solutions if there are any. Thanks for looking.

-Veo

Answer (score 1):

Flash has no way to populate constructor parameters. This is why I [always suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15628239/854556) avoiding constructor parameters for View.  If this is your own Class, I'd suggest to go ahead and fix the parent Class so it doesn't need this.

If it is not, you can use

```
public function VewSubClass() {
   super(null, null);
}
```

I would be concerned here that you actually *need* the Model and controller, so I would make setters available on the View subclass and then populate those variables once the [instance arrives on stage](http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html).

```
public function set model(value:Model):void {
    _model = value;
    //do whatever the super constructor did based on receiving the model
}
public function set controller(value:IController):void {
   _controller = value;
   //etc.
}
```

Note that it probably shouldn't be necessary for the View to know about the controller, and I wouldn't suggest that the *entire* model be given to the View either--just the few properties it needs. So if the Class *is* yours, that puts you into a better position to correct these (IMO) architectural problems.

Based on the signature you've provided, I wouldn't be at *all* surprised to find that the model and controller internal storage are private, rather than protected, which means you're pretty much faced with a rewrite anyway (assuming the model and controller are needed on the View).

Comment: I think I basically did what you're getting at. I realize that stage instances have no way of populating constructor parameters, but for views that are created at runtime, passing those isn't so bad. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Hm, yes, people will be MUCH more likely to help you in the future when they go back and see you've kindly thanked people who helped you in the past in the comments :)

Comment: I must admit that I honestly can't tell if you're being sarcastic or not. :)